# how can we add first 10 integers using while loop in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int howmany;
    int i=0;
    cout <<"How many integers you want to add,just enter the number.\n";
    cin >> howmany;

    while (i < howmany)
    {
          int sum = 0;
          sum = sum +i;
          i++;

          cout << sum << endl;
          }
        system ("pause");  
return 0;

}
```

what is the mistake? It gives me list of numbers rather than their sum.I have tried to change order of statements in loop body but still problem not solved.

Comment: Because you declare and initialize a new instance of `sum` in every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Declare the sum variable out side the loop.

Or

> you can declare a static variable inside loop (static variable will
>   be initialized once)

```
   int main()
{
    int howmany;
    int i=0;
    cout <<"How many integers you want to add,just enter the number.\n";
    cin >> howmany;

     int sum = 0; //Declare here

    while (i < howmany)
    {
          sum = sum +i;
          i++;
    }

    //Display the result after the while loop.
   cout << sum << endl;
        system ("pause");  
   return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialise `sum=0` outside the loop. Because in your code every time you loop, the varaible `sum` is set to `0`.

Change like this

```
int sum = 0;
while (i < howmany)
{
    sum = sum +i;
    i++;

    cout << sum << endl;
}
```